# Converting string to date is not happening inside function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, datetime

I am new to python so this may be a noob question kindly bear with me.

I have a simple function to return daynumber and do some computations based on that value later.

```
def dow(date):
   date=pd.to_datetime(str(date))
   dayNumber=date.weekday()
return dayNumber
```

I am passing string ('yyy-mm-dd') and trying to convert inside the function before calling weekday().
When i call this function and pass string from the same file its working fine.
However when i call this function from different file, the conversion part is not happening i guess.
i am getting the following error
'str' object has no attribute 'weekday'

But when i convert it to datetime from different file and call this function it runs fine. Is there any rule i am violating here.

Calling from the same file using

```
date= '2017-04-17'
x=dow(date)
```

works fine.

Below code is used to call from another python file

```
import demo_v3 as demo
date= '2017-04-17'
x=demo.dow(date)
```

throws me the error('str' object has no attribute 'weekday'), 
However the below code works fine when calling from another python file

```
import demo_v3 as demo
date= '2017-04-17'
date=pd.to_datetime(str(date)) # removing convertion inside function when doing this
x=demo.dow(date)
```

Comment: If you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example it makes it easier for us to help you.  Specifically, to help you, it is best to show us the data and code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Have edited the question with more detail. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't missing anything about date conversion. I was able to run your problematic code without issue.

demo.py

```
import pandas as pd

def dow(date):
    date = pd.to_datetime(str(date))
    dayNumber = date.weekday()
    return dayNumber
```

test.py

```
import demo

def main():
    date= '2017-04-21'
    x=demo.dow(date)
    print(x)

main()
```

Output:

```
>>> 4
```

There were no errors and the output was the correct day of the week (4 == Friday).